# How to avoid toBlocking in RxJava 2

Tags: java, rx-java, rx-java2

Integrating a RxJava in springboot application using `Observable` we are able to get the data from the service. But I have a doubt in using `toBlocking()` method, because I've read many forum postings saying it has issues in production server. See my below code,

Sample Code with `toBlocking()`:

```java
userService.getUsers()
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .toBlocking()
    .single();
```

I want to change the above to get the user object instead of Observable object.
For example:

```java
User user = new User();
userService.getUsers().subscribe(u ->user = u );
```

Here a variable `user` is declared globally in the class it work fine, but inside method it shows an error.

Comment: `toBlocking` is in RxJava 1 only. Also please read the [Getting Started](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava#continuations).

Answer (score 2):

You probably want something like [`blockingFirst`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html#blockingFirst--):

```
final User user = userService
    .getUsers()
    .blockingFirst()
```

I'd encourage you to think about if this is the right thing to do, though (do you really need to block and jump out of the reactive world for this use case?. As @akarnokd said, read [Getting Started](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava#continuations))